# What is the most efficient way to write this program? (details inside)

Tags: python, list

What is the most efficient way to create a program that - creates a list with 0s and 1s (ideally could change but not necersary for what I am doing) - asks for an input - assess the input if it is equal to N then it gets assigned to the first value in the list, E assigned to the second value, S assigned to the third value and W the fourth - then check each list value and if each one is equivalant to 1 it is a possible move and if it is a 0 it is an impossible move.Sorry if that doesnt make much sense hopefully the code is clearer (ironic I know).

```
def movefunc():
    userinput = input("What direction would you like to move, North(N), East(E), South(S), West(W)")
    move = [1,0,1,0]
    N = move[0]
    E = move[1]
    S = move[2]
    W = move[3]
    print(move)
    print(userinput)
    for moves in move:
        if moves == 1:
            print("Possible")  
        elif moves == 0:
            print("Impossible")
        else:
            print("Invalid")
movefunc()
```

This isnt finished because I didnt know how too do some of it. If you can help me in anyway you are a life saver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def movefunc():
    moves = {'N':1, 'E':0, 'S':0, 'W':1}
    user_input = input("What direction would you like to move, North(N), East(E), South(S), West(W)")
    try:
        print('Possible' if moves[user_input] else "Impossible")
    except KeyError:
        print("Invalid")

movefunc()
```

Note, there is room for better structure - e.g. take input in separate function, return from function, instead of printing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to map the input characters to a index into your list:

```py
def movefunc():
    userinput = input("What direction would you like to move, North(N), East(E), South(S), West(W)")
    moves = [1, 0, 1, 0]
    dir_dict = {'N':0, 'E':1, 'S':2, 'W':3}
    if userinput in dir_dict:
        move = moves[dir_dict[userinput]]
        if move == 1:
            print("Possible")  
        else:
            print("Impossible")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

movefunc()
```